# WHMCS use css on specific pages

Tags: whmcs

This question is regarding WHMCS 8.7.X. Is there any way that I can use CSS for specific pages only ?

e.g. in the client area, once the client has logged in, I want to hide the side-bar only on the main client area page (the one which shows right after the client logs into whmcs) and show the side-bar on the rest of the pages.

please help...

Comment: you can use the `ClientAreaHeadOutput` hook for this. Get logged-in status from `$_SESSION` and apply your style depending on `template` name. For more details: 
https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/output/#clientareaheadoutput